# Redirect messages automatically in Telegram

Tags: python, telegram

I want to make automation that gets a message from a group, that we'll call group A.
And send it into group B.

I should use Telegram API or Telegram BOTs to solve this?
And how i can solve this problem using python?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and figured this out:

```
# imports
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import *
import telegram
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# get the telegram bot api_key from environment file
load_dotenv()
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

# you will need the groub_b_id saved as a global variable or
# in some other document
group_b_id = 1234567890

# create the bot, updater, and dispatcher
bot = telegram.Bot(token=API_KEY)
updater = Updater(API_KEY, use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher


def get_chat_id(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # gets the chat_id of the current chat
    global bot
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "This chat's id is: " + str(chat_id))

def auto_forward(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # automatically forwards messages from this chat to
    # chat_b
    
    global bot, group_b_id
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    username = update.effective_message.from_user.name
    chat_title = update.effective_message.chat.title
    msg_txt = update.effective_message.text
    
    bot.send_message(
        group_b_id, 
        text=f"'{msg_txt}'\nwas just sent in chat {chat_title} by {username}"
    )

# sets up the handlers
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('get_chat_id', get_chat_id))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, auto_forward))

# Start the Bot
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

just make sure that you add the bot as an admin to both chats and this will work!